# How do I change my name servers for Sedo Parking?

Tags: dns, parking

I wanted to park my domain with SedoParking.  It says to change it to ns1.sedoparking.com. I did change the start and www to that. But the A (Address) has to be an IP. So How do I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When someone types in www.yourdomain.com, the browser finds out what nameserver your domain points to and then goes to this nameserver to get the dns for www.

To change your nameserver to sedo, you need to contact your domain registrar - it's a different function to your dns, which will then be provided by sedo.

Answer (score 0):

Change NSes in your registrar data only. Zones definitions will appear automagically at sedoparking servers

Comment: So when I'm in the DNS console, should I change start and www to ns1.sedoparking.com and what should I do with the address (@)